# If I keep space in any of the tag, I get error XML document structures must start and end within the same entity

Tags: java, xml

Why am I getting this error if I keep space in any of the tag?

> XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

This is the code:

```
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(path));

Document doc = db.parse(is);
```

My xml data:
path=

```
<user>
    <userdata>
        <salutation>Ms</salutation>
        <firstname>TestUser</firstname>
        <middlename>Tes tMN</middlename>
        <lastname>TestLN</lastname>
        <loginid>testEmail@gmail.com</loginid>
        <display-name>Test User</display-name>
        <email>testEmail@gmail.com</email>
        <isadmin>1</isadmin>
        <mobno>9865323656</mobno>
        <dob>1994/01/02</dob>
        <status>1</status>
    </userdata>
    <operationdata>
        <operationtype>1</operationtype>
    </operationdata>
</user>
```

when I am trying to pass xml data as a string in url with space in data..url breaks..is there any way to handle that?

Comment: this is may be because you added `****` between two tags.

Comment: sorry I tried to make data bold..* is not there in xml

Comment: Are you sure you opened the file correctly? `StingReader` does not take the Path to a File

Comment: path is a string which contains xml data given

Comment: That's a strange name for a variable containing the contents of a file.

Comment: I will change the name..

Comment: You can do this using `Document doc = db.parse(new File("path/to/xml/file"));`

Comment: No I want to pass xml data as a string only

Comment: If I remove space..it works fine..but, I want to make it work with space also

Comment: Your example works fine for me with `<middlename>Tes tMN</middlename>`. Demo: https://ideone.com/8Jve4R

Comment: I saw your code but. I dont know why it is not wotking when I am passing this string data as a parameter with url..

Comment: Can you Base64 encode your string and add it to your example? (`Base64.getEncoder().encode(path.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`). My guess is that there are some odd non-printing chars in your string.

Comment: No, I cant do that..because I want user to pass this string xml in url..what if I keep values as a attribute in userdata tag?